# counting and subtotaling large amounts of data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have created a Pivot Table in Excel 2010 to subtotal large amounts of data. I work for an automotive company and so have to count and track Models rolling out to my dealerships. I currently use a Pivot table to calculate the totals of each of the Models but I need to break it down more than just the Model level. I also need to split within some of the models based on color, 2DR or 4DR, Cylender 2WD or 4WD.

I can't figure out how to get a Pivot table to go deeper in it's calculation with the criteria changing all over the place like this. Can someone please help me come up with an idea as to what I can do? I would really appreaciate any help at all. A sample of my data is:

I need totals of models by Door/Cyl, 2WD/4WD, Hybrid or not. Right now it's a nightmare manual set up.

I need help with either a better Pivot Table, Lookup formulas or should I push it to Microsoft Access to Query it?? I need to have excel count how many of each of these I have, plus counting how many of each color is being produced.

Sorry if I can't explain it better.  I don't know how to attach an Excel file or if it's possible here.

MODEL ID color Trim Trans Model Door Cyl

CT2B8DJNW RE/BK EX-LV6 6AT ACCORD 2 6,
CR2E3DEW GY/BK LX 6MT ACCORD 4 4,
CR2F3DEW BE/IV LX CVT ACCORD 4 4,
CR3F8DJNW BK/BK EX-LV6 6AT ACCORD 4 6,
YF3H2DEW SX/GR 2WD LX 5AT PILOT 5 6,
YF4H4DEW SX/GR 4WD EX 5AT PILOT 5 6,
RM3H3DEW BK/BK 2WD LX 5AT CR-V 5 4,
RM4H5EJW BK/BK AWDEX 5AT CR-V 5 4,
FB2F9DJNW WA/BK EX-L 5AT CIVIC 4 4,
FB6E5DJVW WH/BK SI 6MT CIVIC 4 4,
FG3B5DEW BX/BK LX 5AT CIVIC 2 4,
TF1H5DKNW WA/BK 2EXLNV6 6AT CROSSTOUR 5 6,
TF2H5DJNW BK/BK 4EXLV6 6AT CROSSTOUR 5 6,
FB4F2DGW BK/GR HYBNAVI CVT CIVIC IMA 4 4,

Thank you so much for reviewing for me,

R71lima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else might know pivot tables better than me, but I know databases.

I think long term you might be better off with an Access database.
select count(*) from tablename where color=red and wheels=4 and door=2

SQL allows you to ask for any columns, omitting columns at will.  There is a "Group by" and "order by" function.  MS Access has a nice graphical interface to help write the queries for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I finally figured out the new Pivot Table in Excel 2010 and how it can count for me.  Now I just need someone to help me manually define how to Subtotal and manually sort within the Pivot Table to pull it all together.  I loved your idea about Access and posed it to my manager however he wants me to stick to Excel due to the lack of Access knowledge in my department.  Thank you so much for all your help